# How to wait for a Docker container to be removed

Tags: docker

I have a task that I run in a docker container. I only want one instance of it running, so I name the container. Occasionally I need to modify the code or configuration so I rebuild the image, and then stop and re-start the container with the new image. I'd been doing a `docker stop` followed by a `docker run`.

Recently, I tried to combine these into a single step:

```
docker stop myTask &&
    docker run --rm -d myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

However, this fails with:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/myTask" is already in use by container "49d806e25655a5e6f5309cc5509b54a10b4f0c84e60fad39856777881c99e9ce". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

I then tried adding a `docker wait` in there:

```
docker stop myTask &&
    (docker wait myTask || true) &&
    docker run --rm -d myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

I still get this behavior. It seems `docker wait` only waits for the container to stop, but does not wait for it to be removed. I then tried using `docker rm`, thinking that it must surely wait for the container to be removed before returning:

```
docker stop myTask &&
    (docker rm myTask || true) &&
    docker run --rm -d myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

This *still* fails with a "The container name "/myTask" is already in use" error.

How can I block until there is no container with a given name?

Comment: So the responses are here so far (summarized):
1. Forcibly remove (rm -f) with SIGKILL instead of graceful stopping
2. Polling periodically with sleep
3. Rename after stop
None of them is perfect, in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping the container is not the same as removing it. You have a race condition after the container stops between the server side remove operation (enabled with the `--rm`) and the `docker run` command.

You can explicitly remove the container instead of just stopping it:

```
docker rm -f myTask &&
  docker run --rm -d myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

Or you can poll for it to be removed:

```
docker stop myTask &&
    while docker container inspect myTask >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done &&
    docker run --rm -d myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

Comment: I mentioned that stopping and removing are not the same in the question. The last code snippet in the question does an `rm` before the `run`, and it still fails with the same error.

Comment: Did your `docker rm` throw any errors? Perhaps "Remove already in progress"?

Comment: Looks like it, yes. Honestly, that seems like pretty odd behavior. I want it removed, and I want to wait until it's removed. Why isn't there a way to wait for the other removal to complete. Using `docker rm -f` in place of `docker stop` does work, but it does a SIGKILL rather than the SIGTERM followed by SIGKILL the way `docker stop` does, which seems unfortunate.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves it is less than ideal, hence the second option that does the polling. Switching to `docker-compose` or swarm mode would also avoid these issues since those rely on declaring a target state rather than an imperative list of commands to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command instead:

```
docker rm -f myTask && docker run --rm -d --name myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

Comment: Is that different from the one I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for removal you might also use:

```
docker stop myTask && docker rename myTask myTaskStopped
docker run --rm -d myTask myImage:$VERSION
```

The stopped container is removed in background while the new container is being started without name conflicts.

Comment: What do you think of renaming first before stopping? In this case you'll avoid race condition, and guarantee that container still exists for all the following commands